# Rename filter values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is supposed to change the "WEEK"-filter on 5 pivot tables on the sheet "veckorapport".

This macro somehow changes "name" on the weeks to the number/text i put in the input box. See first picture, this numbers should be in descending order.

[image: Filter in pivot]

My code:

```
Sub Veckorapport_filter()
Dim num As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("Veckorapport")
num = InputBox(Prompt:="Vecka", Title:="ENTER WEEK")
sht.PivotTables("PivotTable1") _
    .PivotFields("WEEK").CurrentPage = num
sht.PivotTables("PivotTable2") _
    .PivotFields("WEEK").CurrentPage = num
sht.PivotTables("PivotTable3") _
    .PivotFields("WEEK").CurrentPage = num
sht.PivotTables("PivotTable4") _
    .PivotFields("WEEK").CurrentPage = num
sht.PivotTables("PivotTable5") _
    .PivotFields("WEEK").CurrentPage = num
End Sub
```

I need help with two things: How can i write this code so it doesn't change "name" on the Weeks in the filter?

And 2nd: How can i change back the names to the proper names in the filter-list?

Link to picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI3J5.jpg

EDIT: Picture how it should look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmvxQ.jpg

EDIT 2: Those two weeks have switched places. It should be in descending order: https://imgur.com/PVS3JMf

Comment: *This macro **somehow** changes "name" on the weeks to the number/text i put in the input box.*  Did someone else write this code?

Comment: I am responsible for this code and it worked until I noticed that it changes the name of the filter values...

Comment: I used the "record macro" feature and puzzled this together to make it work. But I am 100% sure there is a better way that works properly. I just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Is your goal to refilter based on your input, or is it intended to change a name?  If you want to refilter, you would `.clearfilter` then `.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionIsBetween` specifying your range.  To change the names/labels displaying in the filter itself, you would need to affect the data.

Comment: Yes I want to refilter with the new value I put in to the input box. Obviously I need to clear filter first... Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: If you clear the filters first, then assigning an invalid value to the `Currentpage` will cause a run-time error. If you don't clear the filter first, it simply overwrites the caption, as you found. On that note, you should at least be testing that *something* was input before proceeding... :)

Comment: Is it possible to create a Loop that loops trough pivot tables and changes the weeks on all 5 tables? And i might change the input box to a drop down list instead with WEEKs 1-52 preprogrammed.

Comment: @Sam `Dim pt AS PivotTable: For each pt In Sheet1.PivotTables: pt.PivotFields("Week").CurrentPage = num: Next pt` will change all the Pivot Tables in Sheet 1.  Or, `For x = 1 to 5: Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable" & x).PivotFields...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `.CurrentPage` to something that *does not exist*, then it will instead rename the currently selected page/item.  (If you do this manually, instead of via VBA, then you will get a confirmation box, "No item of this name exists in the PivotTable report.  Rename 'Old_Name' to 'New_Name'?" with an "OK" and "Cancel" button)

You can partially prevent this by ensuring that "Show Items without Data" is turned on for that field, and/or you can use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to check if that value exists before changing the `.CurrentPage`

As for resetting the items:  Set the `.Name`, `.Value` or `.Caption` of the `PivotItem` back to the `SourceName`:

```
Dim piTMP AS PivotItem, pfTMP AS PivotField
Set pfTMP = sht.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WEEK")
For Each piTMP In pfTMP.PivotItems
    piTMP.Name = piTMP.SourceName
Next piTMP
```

If the names have been switched for 2 items, you will run into an issue (the same name cannot exist twice), so you either need to check for the name being in use, or to just brute-force it with 2 loops - which is probably the simpler solution to write:

```
Dim piTMP AS PivotItem, pfTMP AS PivotField
Set pfTMP = sht.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("WEEK")
'Once through
For Each piTMP In pfTMP.PivotItems
    piTMP.Name = piTMP.SourceName & "_AndSomeTextThatYouNeverUse"
Next piTMP
'Twice through
For Each piTMP In pfTMP.PivotItems
    piTMP.Name = piTMP.SourceName
Next piTMP
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! This code changed the blank name to "13" which is correct, but then after that i get a "Invalid procedure call or argument" error.

Comment: It fills the blank name with the right number, but the two last weeks are switched and the code does not seem to know how to work here.

Comment: @Sam Run through once, and rename all the fields to something that they can't be mistakenly called, then go back through and reset them?  Seems simpler than using `On Errror...` for a `Try...Catch...` check to see if the name is already in use.

Comment: How do I rename them manually? This all happened by mistake from that horrible macro i made.

Comment: @Sam Select the item in the Pivot Table, then overtype it.  You will get the message I mentioned in the first paragraph.  (Or, you can use the new code at the end to reset them)

Answer (score 1):

To loop through all pivot tables on the sheet:

```
Sub Veckorapport_filter()
Dim num As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("Veckorapport")
num = InputBox(Prompt:="Vecka", Title:="ENTER WEEK")
If len(num) <> 0 then
  dim pt as pivottable
  for each pt in sht.pivottables
    with pt.PivotFields("WEEK")
       .clearallfilters
      .CurrentPage = num
    end with
  next pt
 end if
End Sub
```